# How to get particular record from database with image by using customadapter

Tags: android, android-listview, android-asynctask, nullpointerexception, custom-adapter

Hi myself newbie to android ,I have already done with code of searching  a particular record from database and displaying it list using simple cursor adapter, to get image also with data I started using custom-adapter, code work very well when I try to retrieve all data from db but when I pass parameter to method in db to search for particular record and display it in list error comes up

Here is my code 
code which is pass when user selects data to be displayed

```
    Intent i= new Intent(SearchByBed.this,SearchBedView.class);
    Bundle bbed= new Bundle();
    bbed.putString("bedValue", spinn_Bed.getSelectedItem().toString());
    i.putExtras(bbed);
    startActivity(i);
```

In this part passed parameter from previous class is catch and then pass to db and want to retrieve record plus bind it to custom-adapter

```
my asynctask code


public class loadSomeStuff extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
    ProgressDialog dialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(SearchBedView.this);
        dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        dialog.setMax(100);
        dialog.setMessage("Loading Data");
        dialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        dialog.incrementProgressBy(values[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            publishProgress(5);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        dialog.dismiss();

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        displaydemo();

    }


}

public void displaydemo() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Bundle bbedview = this.getIntent().getExtras();

     name = bbedview.getString("name").toString();    
     //data.setText(name);   //as per log here i was getting null pointer exception but  

     //know commented as it was line from my previous code 

    info = new PropertyInfo(this);
    info.open();
    cursor = info.getBed(name);
    String[] from = new String[] { PropertyInfo.KEY_ROWID,
            PropertyInfo.KEY_TYPE, PropertyInfo.KEY_BEDROOMS,
            PropertyInfo.KEY_STATUS, PropertyInfo.KEY_CITY,
            PropertyInfo.KEY_FURNISHING, PropertyInfo.KEY_TOTPRICE };
    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.rowId, R.id.rowtype, R.id.rowBed,
            R.id.rowStatus, R.id.rowCity, R.id.rowFurnish,
            R.id.rowTotalPrice };
    custAdapter = new CustomContactsAdapterBedView(this, R.layout.row, cursor,
            from, to);

    this.setListAdapter(custAdapter);
           }
```

while this is mycustomadapter class

```
 public class CustomContactsAdapterBedView extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

    private int layout;
    LayoutInflater inflator;
    TextView tid,ttype,tbed,tstatus,tcity,tfurnish,ttotprice;

    public CustomContactsAdapterBedView(Context context, int layout, Cursor                    c,
            String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, layout, c, from, to, 0);
        this.layout = layout;
        inflator = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }


    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = inflator.inflate(layout, parent, false);
        return v;
    }


    @Override
    public void bindView(View v, final Context context, Cursor c) {
        final String id = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(PropertyInfo.KEY_ROWID));
        final String type = c
                .getString(c.getColumnIndex(PropertyInfo.KEY_TYPE));
        final String bed = c.getString(c
                .getColumnIndex(PropertyInfo.KEY_BEDROOMS));
        final String status = c.getString(c
                .getColumnIndex(PropertyInfo.KEY_STATUS));
        final String city = c
                .getString(c.getColumnIndex(PropertyInfo.KEY_CITY));
        final String furnish = c.getString(c
                .getColumnIndex(PropertyInfo.KEY_FURNISHING));
        final String totprice = c.getString(c
                .getColumnIndex(PropertyInfo.KEY_TOTPRICE));
        final byte[] image = c.getBlob(c.getColumnIndex(PropertyInfo.IMAGE));
        ImageView iv = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.photo);

        if (image != null) {
            if (image.length > 3) {
                iv.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image, 0,
                        image.length));
            }
        }

        tid = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.rowId);
        tid.setText(id);

        ttype = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.rowtype);
        ttype.setText(type);

        tbed = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.rowBed);
        tbed.setText(bed);

        tstatus = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.rowStatus);
        tstatus.setText(status);

        tcity = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.rowCity);
        tcity.setText(city);

        tfurnish = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.rowFurnish);
        tfurnish.setText(furnish);

        ttotprice = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.rowTotalPrice);
        ttotprice.setText(totprice);

    }
}
```

And method in db is as followed

```
         public Cursor getBed(String l) {
    String[] columns = new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_TITLE, KEY_TYPE,
            KEY_BEDROOMS, KEY_STATUS, KEY_CITY, KEY_LOCALITY, KEY_PRICE,
            KEY_TOTPRICE, KEY_FURNISHING, KEY_BALCONIES, KEY_BATHROOM,
            IMAGE };
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, KEY_BEDROOMS
            + "=" + l, null, null, null, null);
    return c;

}
```

And error in logcat is

```
          05-16 20:33:43.803: E/AndroidRuntime(31444): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
          05-16 20:33:43.803: E/AndroidRuntime(31444): java.lang.NullPointerException
          05-16 20:33:43.803: E/AndroidRuntime(31444):  at 

          com.project.realestate.SearchBedView.displaydemo(SearchBedView.java:299)
          05-16 20:33:43.803: E/AndroidRuntime(31444):  at 

        com.project.realestate.SearchBedView$loadSomeStuff.onPostExecute(SearchBedView.java:281)
         05-16 20:33:43.803: E/AndroidRuntime(31444):   at 

      com.project.realestate.SearchBedView$loadSomeStuff.onPostExecute(SearchBedView.java:1)
         05-16 20:33:43.803: E/AndroidRuntime(31444):   at 
         android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
         05-16 20:33:43.803: E/AndroidRuntime(31444):   at   
         android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
         05-16 20:33:43.803: E/AndroidRuntime(31444):   at  
         android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
         05-16 20:33:43.803: E/AndroidRuntime(31444):   at  
         android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
         05-16 20:33:43.803: E/AndroidRuntime(31444):   at  
         android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
         05-16 20:33:43.803: E/AndroidRuntime(31444):   at   
         android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
         05-16 20:33:43.803: E/AndroidRuntime(31444):   at
         java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
         05-16 20:33:43.803: E/AndroidRuntime(31444):   at 
         java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
         05-16 20:33:43.803: E/AndroidRuntime(31444):   at  
        com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
        05-16 20:33:43.803: E/AndroidRuntime(31444):    at
        com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
        05-16 20:33:43.803: E/AndroidRuntime(31444):    at 
        dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

please help me with my code

Comment: hey somebody plz helppp

Comment: have you applied AsyncTask ??

Comment: @bhavana yes as before data gets load from db i am showing a progress bar in onpreexecute and in onpostexecute i call method name displaydemo whose full code is written at top

Comment: ok...then check the value which u r passing to Async class....it may happens value which you are passing is null...thats why your application is crashing.

Comment: @bhavana c i am getting selection so that which row should be displayed from one class and pass it through using bundle to another class i have similarly use it in simplecursoradapter but know it shows null value when it fetches so cant get what should i write their

Comment: please post your Asynclass code and how u are calling that class, post full code if possible

Comment: @bhavana have edited code have a look and help to resolve error

Comment: @bhavana Ok i have removed data (textview) widget as i was using it in previous code format so that issue is solve but though my db has such data it dosent show that record

Answer (score 0):

```
data.setText(name);
```

I guess the data is EditText or A textView have you got the reference to it with findViewById

you have to enclose string value with single quote and escape sequence i have modified the line

```
Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, KEY_BEDROOMS
        + "=\'" +l+"\'", null, null, null, null);
```

Comment: Ok i have removed data (textview) widget as i was using it in previous code format so that issue is solve but though my db has such data it dosent show that record

Answer (score 0):

where you have defined "data" for TextView (or whatever widget it is) ??

It should be defined like:

**TextView data = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.*yourTextView*);**

Comment: Ok i have removed data (textview) widget as i was using it in previous code format so that issue is solve but though my db has such data it dosent show that record